# When can I remove the El Capitan install drive?

Tags: usb, macos, install

I have installed 10.11 from a USB drive, it has run as expected and I am now at the "Create account" screen (input name+username).

I will now turn the computer over to the person who will do the remaining steps.
Can I remove the USB drive at this point without problems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can now remove the install media and shut down the computer. Once the machine reboots into the Setup Assistant, it's safe to remove the install media.

Comment: For reference, could you add when exactly it becomes safe to do so?

Comment: @timothymh Edited answer